# Find specific substring in sys.stdin and discard everything up to the point where the substring occurs from the input

Tags: python, python-3.x

My program gets input from `sys.stdin`.

I want to find a specific substring in the input provided in `sys.stdin` and continue analysis from the point where the substring occurs using, e.g:

```
for line in sys.stdin:
   tokens = line.split()
...
```

How would I do that?

My initial attempt is something like the above, but when I find the substring, I want to provide the rest of the input to some other utility function.

Comment: Do you mean you want to start processing from the line **after** the pattern occurred?

Comment: Yeah, that would be OK. Either with the line included or not (it doesn't matter).

Comment: Create a flag that becomes `True` when you find the substring like `if substring in line: started = True` ...off you go...

Comment: Can I then pass sys.stdin to another function and continue from the next line?